# Android ViewFlipper Animation

Tags: android

I'm stuck on a simple problem which is driving me nuts. Basically I have 2 ImageViews, I'm trying to have the first show for a second, then fade out to show the second. I've been looking into using ViewFlipper, example code below, but the animation is non-existent.

```
ViewFlipper mFlipper = new ViewFlipper(this);

ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
i.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c1));
ImageView i2 = new ImageView(this);
i2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c2));

mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        R.anim.fade));
mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        R.anim.fade));
mFlipper.addView(i);
mFlipper.addView(i2);
mFlipper.startFlipping();
setContentView(mFlipper);
```

I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track using a viewFlipper so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see no problems with your code, when I use the standard `android.R.anim.fade_in` and `android.R.anim.fade_out`.  This leads me to believe that the issue has to do with your fade animations; try using the built-in Android fades and see if that helps.

Also, you should be using `ImageView.setImageResource()` or  `ImageView.setImageDrawable()` rather than `ImageView.setBackgroundDrawable()`.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried:

```
    mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             R.anim.fade_in));
     mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
             R.anim.fade_out));
```

Taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html)

Comment: I'm getting syntax error - "Cannot resolve symbol fade_in". Can you please help with that?