# Simple navigation animation with android

Tags: android, animation

I'm looking for a simple animation example using the android SDK for displaying a little animation between views.

Basically when we have a list view and a detail view - lets have a 'transition' animation between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewSwitcher` supports all kind of `Animation` and is very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. I found the animation I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919169/android-viewflipper-animation.

Comment: very useful answer!  The thing is that ViewSwitcher extends ViewAnimator so you can apply any kind of animation to it using setInAnimation & setOutAnimation .. 10q

Answer (score 0):

You can use [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,int)) on API 5 and above. Alternatively, you could have a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html), with the detail and list activity in one.