# Android cube transition between two views

Tags: android, view, 3d, android-animation

Is it possible to implement a cube like 3D transition between two views?

I got two `FrameLayouts`, previous to the animation layout 1 is visible, after the animation layout 2 should become visible and layout 2 gone. The transition between should look like cube transition in GO Launcher.

I found no way to implement this. Are there any libs or other helpful ways to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3D flip example in Google's ApiDemos. I think you can take this as a good starting point...

http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: I still tried it and implemented a nice flip animation, but I found no hint for a cube effect.

Answer (score 0):

[Simple navigation animation with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659403/simple-navigation-animation-with-android) This thread has the beginnings of what you need.

ViewFlipper and ViewSwitcher will help.