# Flip Page in PDF Viewer in Android

Tags: android, pdf

i have create simple PDF Viewer that browse PDF file. now i want to add some animation in my app. like flip page left to right or vice versa when user change page by touch. anyone have idea how to do this?

ThanX
Piyush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can also use **Image Switcher** if yr pdf is converted to images... & check the API Demo Example for adding Animations to it..

Comment: i m also trying to create a pdf viewer.. m using Vudroid open source.. i utlimately want it to be converted to images or text.. wud u like to share the API or opensource that u used for doing it??

Answer (score 0):

I would try and use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html), it can be used to 'flip' between views and [show animations while doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919169/android-viewflipper-animation)